# EnableVisualStyles....how can I reset this?

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio

My EnableVisualStyles() is not working anymore. I now get forms with a green line around it, it's horrible. How can I fix this? When I start a new project it's the same. I think about un-installing visual studio and reinstall it, but there should be a better way I think/hope. Does anyone know the solution?

PS I tried the Application.DoEvents() method, but this is not the answer for me.

[an example of how my form looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFduE.jpg)

```
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
```

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you run your application on a different PC? Maybe it's just the local PC that's changed.

Comment: Thnx! I have no idea. I've only one PC. It worked fine....till I commented that line (Application.EnableVisualStyles();). After uncommenting it, it didn't go back to normal.

Comment: I strongly suggest that something else happened beyond just commenting/uncommenting that line. Did you install any new software, change any settings, etc? Are any other application windows affected?

Comment: I don't think I did anything like that. Just creating a class...                                               public ProgressBarColor()
        {
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
        }                                                                      can this be the problem you think? I have removed it and used the default progressbar, but this was not the problem....i still had the weerd look and feel.

Comment: all projects are affected...so it seams something changed in Visual Studio...but what?? Other software still looks the same.

Comment: A search on "green borders around windows" suggests that some AV software (and similar) may apply such overlays to indicate when programs have been sandboxed - so maybe check your AV settings.

Comment: That did it!!! Wow! Thank you very much. Comodo blocked my projects! I googled on green borders myself but found nothing, so many thanks!!

Comment: Hi Damien, can I give you a good recommendation or something on this platform? I'm new here, so don't know yet how this works.